# Is it possible to add a ScrollView to a AppBarLayout

Tags: android, android-scrollview, android-coordinatorlayout, android-nestedscrollview

I need to work with two `ScrollView`s. One inside `AppBarLayout` and the other outside.

For the outside `ScrollView`, I'm using a `NestedScrollView` with the `appbar_scrolling_view_behavior` and it's working correctly.

For the inside, I'm using an `Scrollview` with `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"`

My problem is that the `NestedScrollView` seems to override the `ScrollView` events, even if I touch the `ScrollView` area, the `NestedScrollView` is the one that scrolls.

Is there any way I could do that?

**See the code below:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"    
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap">

            <TextView                
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>  

        </ScrollView>       
     </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

     <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <TextView                
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>   

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```